# problem with using Element.remove function in js

Tags: javascript

I used js code from web to create dragable element, it should appear when i press ctrl key and it worked. But then i wanted to add function to delate it when i relase ctrl key.

And now its only create multiple elements when i keep pushing ctrl key and doing nothing when i relase it.

Please help, i dont know what im doing wrong :(

Ok i edited code, hope now its looks better. Sorry im noob in programming, im just starting soo thats why my code looks like crap :(

For now i deleted function for Element.prototype.remove() becouse its not working anyway. My question is how add it to this code. How make it working when i relese ctrl key.

I also discovered that code works not only with ctrl key, but with any key. Also when im keep pushing any key it keeps spawning same object again and again

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey)
    var mousePosition;
    var offset = [0, 0];
    var div;
    var isDown = false;

    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.left = "-100px";
    div.style.top = "-100px";
    div.style.width = "200px";
    div.style.height = "200px";
    div.style.background = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)";
    div.style.color = "black";

    document.body.appendChild(div);

    div.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e) {
      isDown = true;
      offset = [div.offsetLeft - e.clientX, div.offsetTop - e.clientY];
    },
    true
  );

document.addEventListener( "mouseup",function() {
      isDown = false;
    },
    true
  );

document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
        if (isDown) {
          mousePosition = {
            x: event.clientX,
            y: event.clientY,
            };
        
          div.style.left = mousePosition.x + offset[0] + "px";
          div.style.top = mousePosition.y + offset[1] + "px";

          moveX = mousePosition.x + offset[0] + "px";
          moveY = mousePosition.y + offset[1] + "px";

      }
    },
    true
  );
});
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation so your code is readable? And maybe create a [mre]?

Comment: Why assign a new function for `Element.prototype.remove()`? What's wrong with the [existing one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)?

Comment: Also overwriting the prototype every `keyup` seems like an unnecessary thing to do. Same goes for adding a (global) event listener every `keydown`